# Hibernate: could not read column value from result set:Fail to convert to internal representation

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to fetch values from DB. i have configured hibernate successfully. below is my hbm file and pojo class.

```
<class name="UserMasterBean" table="EMPLOYEE_MASTER">
    <id name="Id" type="long">
        <column name="EMP_ID" length="10" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="FirstName" type="string">
        <column name="EMP_FIRST_NAME" length="30" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="SecondName" type="string">
        <column name="EMP_SECOND_NAME" length="30" />
    </property>
    <property name="LastName" type="string">
        <column name="EMP_LAST_NAME" length="30" />
    </property>

    <property name="empDob" type="date">
        <column name="EMP_DOB" length="7" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="empDoj" type="date">
        <column name="EMP_DOJ" length="7" not-null="true" />
    </property>
    <property name="empPermAdd1" type="string">
        <column name="EMP_PERM_ADD1" length="50" not-null="true" />
    </property>
<!--Other Properties removed-->
```

below is my pojo class

```
public class UserMasterBean {

private Long id;
private String loginName;
private String password;
private String type;
private String loginYN;
private String salutation;
private String firstName;
private String secondName;
private String lastName;
private String gender;
private String maritalStatus;
private String pagerNo;
private String phoneNo;
private String mobileNo;
private String emailId;
private String personalMailId;
private Long companyId;
private String companyName;
private Long worldWideRegion;
private Long country;
private Long localRegion;
private Long state;
private Long city;
private Long department;
private String curriculum;
private String dn;
private String photoPath;
private java.sql.Timestamp empDob;
private java.sql.Timestamp empDoj;
private java.sql.Timestamp empDol;
private java.sql.Timestamp empDoc;
private String empPanNo;
private String empBloodGroup;
private String empCurrcBand;
private String empPassportNo;
private String empManager;


public String getFieldPrefix() {
    return fieldPrefix;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getLoginName() {
    return loginName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public String getLoginYN() {
    return loginYN;
}

public String getSalutation() {
    return salutation;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getSecondName() {
    return secondName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
/* Amit Gupte - Modified - IUser Begin */

public String getMiddleName() {
    return secondName;
}

public String getName() {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
/* Amit Gupte - Modified - IUser End*/

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public String getMaritalStatus() {
    return maritalStatus;
}

public String getPagerNo() {
    return pagerNo;
}

public String getPhoneNo() {
    return phoneNo;
}

public String getMobileNo() {
    return mobileNo;
}

public String getEmailId() {
    return emailId;
}

public String getPersonalMailId() {
    return personalMailId;
}

public Long getCompanyId() {
    return companyId;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public Long getWorldWideRegion() {
    return worldWideRegion;
}

public Long getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public Long getLocalRegion() {
    return localRegion;
}

public Long getState() {
    return state;
}

public Long getCity() {
    return city;
}

public Long getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public String getCurriculum() {
    return curriculum;
}

public String getDn() {
    return dn;
}

public String getPhotoPath() {
    return photoPath;
}

public java.sql.Timestamp getEmpDob() {
    return empDob;
}

public java.sql.Timestamp getEmpDoj() {
    return empDoj;
}

public java.sql.Timestamp getEmpDol() {
    return empDol;
}

public java.sql.Timestamp getEmpDoc() {
    return empDoc;
}

public String getEmpPanNo() {
    return empPanNo;
}

public String getEmpBloodGroup() {
    return empBloodGroup;
}

public String getEmpCurrcBand() {
    return empCurrcBand;
}

public String getEmpPassportNo() {
    return empPassportNo;
}

public String getEmpManager() {
    return empManager;
}



//Other methods removed
```

}

I am facing below error.

```
Sep 04, 2013 11:50:19 AM org.hibernate.type.NullableType nullSafeGet
INFO: could not read column value from result set: EMP1_0_; Fail to convert to internal           representation
Sep 04, 2013 11:50:19 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 17059, SQLState: 99999
Sep 04, 2013 11:50:19 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: Fail to convert to internal representation
```

I am not getting what is wrong with my code.

I querying as

```
String hql = "from UserMasterBean";
    List empList = attendance.getList(hql, factory);
```

for other classes its working

Comment: May be posting query part of your code useful...instead of pojo

Comment: this is my query String hql = "from UserMasterBean";
    List empList = attendance.getList(hql, factory);

Comment: More details needed to give you a precise answer, but have a look at your data which is being loaded. It seems that there is null value for one of columns that you have marked as not-null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is thrown when getInt (or some other numeric type) is called for a VARCHAR value that is not the string representation of a number. If a VARCHAR column contains 'BOB' and you call getInt on that column, you'll get this error.

Comment: problem solved. There was problem in defining type. in database it was varchar but while defining in pojo i had used as Long. Thanks.

Comment: In my case, it was an Enum that I forgot to annotate with `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`, so it was trying to `getInt`, which is the default for Enums... I always forget that u.u

Comment: This error from different post quite pointed out that there is some problem with the datatype mapping. I was just looking at the id of the entity, but there was a field with Boolean representation i forgot to add the type of convertion. I had the database data type as char in the entity i was trying to give boolean but didnt give the type and hence i was getting the error. Defining the type solved the problem for me.
`@Type(type="yes_no")`