# org.hibernate.type.NullableType nullSafeGet could not read column value from result set: Numeric Overflow

Tags: java, hibernate, resultset

```
Hibernate:
   <id name="A" column="A" type="integer"></id>  
  <property name="B" column="B" type="integer"/>
  <property name ="ID" column="ID" type="string"/>
  <property name="REASON" column="REASON" type="string"/>
  <property name="TEST" column="TEST" type="string"/>
  <property name="C" column="C" type="string"/>
  <property name="UNIT" column="UNIT" type="string"/>   
  <property name="NO" column="NO" type="integer"/>      
  <property name="LIMIT" column="LIMIT" type="string"/>
  <property name="MAX_LIMIT" column="LIMIT" type="string"/>
  <property name="MEASURED_VALUE" column="MEASURED_VALUE" type="string"/>
  <property name="TEST_POINT" column="TEST_POINT" type="string"/>
  <property name="CD" column="CD" type="string"/>
  <property name="AID" column="AID" type="string"/>
  <property name="MID" column="MID" type="string"/>
  <property name="LAST_UPDATE_DT" column="LAST_UPDATE_DT"  />
```

Java:

```
private String ID;
private String MAX_LIMIT;
private String LIMIT;
private Date CREATE_DT;
private Integer A;
private Integer B;
private String C;
private Date LAST_UPDATE_DT;
private String MEASURED_VALUE;
private String MID;
private String ID;
private String REASON;
private String CD;
private Integer NO;
private String TEST;
private String UNIT;
private String TEST_POINT;
```

Error:

```
000001c7 IntegerType   I org.hibernate.type.NullableType nullSafeGet could not read column value from result set: A; Numeric Overflow
```

000001c7 JDBCException W org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions SQL Error: 17026, SQLState: 99999
000001c7 JDBCException E org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions Numeric Overflow

DB:

```
A NUMBER(12)
B NUMBER(12)
TEST_POINT VARCHAR2(20 Byte)
C VARCHAR2(4 Byte)
TEST VARCHAR2(25 Byte)
UNIT VARCHAR2(15 Byte)
MEASURED_VALUE VARCHAR2(13 Byte)
LIMIT VARCHAR2(13 Byte)
MAX_LIMIT VARCHAR2(13 Byte)
CD VARCHAR2(10 Byte)
AID VARCHAR2(3 Byte)
MID VARCHAR2(10 Byte)
NO NUMBER(3)
CREATE_DT DATE
LAST_UPDATE_DT DATE
ID VARCHAR2(6 Byte)
REASON VARCHAR2(100 Byte)
```

How to resolve the error?

Comment: Can you show us the JDBC code where you execute the query which caused this error?

Comment: `session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(); 
           session.createCriteria(VO.class);
       Query q = session.createQuery(BusinessConstants.);
       q.setInteger(0,dSeq);
       q.setFetchSize(1000);
       List results = q.list();
       Iterator it = results.iterator();
       VO  TestInfo = null;
       while(it.hasNext())
       {
        TestInfo = (VO)it.next();
        TestInfo.setCseq(TestInfo.getA().toString());
        l.add(TestInfo);
       }`

Comment: This code, in addition to being almost not readable, is missing the actual query which you ran.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606886/hibernate-could-not-read-column-value-from-result-setfail-to-convert-to-intern) might be useful to you.